# Trying to add giosg tag to Wix

Tags: html, tags

Our partner gave us a tag that i should add to our wix webpage, but the i have absolutely no idea where to start. Also, for rookie like myself i find the wix manuals overwhelming to understand. I've tried to add html iframe to page and add the tag there but it didn't work. I've tried to add the tag to the page code but i guess that it's not that simple.

The followin is the tag:

(function(w, t, f) {  var s='script',o='_giosg',h='https://service.giosg.com',e,n;e=t.createElement(s);e.async=1;e.src=h+'/live/';  w[o]=w[o]||function(){(w[o]._e=w[o]._e||[]).push(arguments)};w[o]._c=f;w[o]._h=h;n=t.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(e,n);})(window,document,3513);

Any kind of help or advices are welcome!
Thanks

Comment: Where did you add it? What does this tag do?

Comment: Hi Philip and sorry for late comment.

This tag should add a chat window to our website that would connect a page visitor with our partner company. 

I've tried to add HTML iFrame to our company webpage and at the tag there, but nothing happens. I'm not sure if i should connect the partner companys domain to this tag?